# Oracle : Same Query taking different time on two different machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, database-tuning

I have oracle database schema on my local machine and same schema is present on server machine as well, but time taken to execute same Query by:
Server Machine : 17.45 Seconds
Local Machine : 3.05 Seconds
P.S : Server configuration is far much better than local machine's Configuration

I have generated the explain plan from both schema's both giving almost same execution plan
Explain plan

local Explain plan
[image]

Server Explain plan
[image]

Don't know if the issue is related to Disk,CPU,I/O management (DBA) of the server machine.
Please provide me the inputs database tuning if there are any.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the amount of data comparable between your local machine and the server machine, please poste both explain plan in text format along with your query.

Comment: The posted explain plan shows a full table s an of 115000 rows, taking 3 seconds. So I guess this is your Development run. Please post the production plan. Almost the same is not identical, and the difference may be crucial to understanding your question.

Comment: @APC I have added snapshots for both explain plan